# MySQL for each member, get all matches they played in?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with columns memberIds and matchIds, is there a way I can query all the matches each member has played in, without using cursors?

So member 1 might have played in match 3, 4, 5, member 2 played in match 1, 4, 8, etc. I want  to get it returning in this sort of style

```
memberId   |   Played In Matches

1          |   3, 4, 5

2          |   1, 4, 8
```

Comment: `select memberId,group_concat(matchIds) as played from table_name group by memberId`

Answer (score 0):

read up on GROUP BY and GROUP_CONCAT(), that should do it for you